# how to clear entry field and deselect the radio button in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4

```
            self.hash_radio=StringVar()
            ttk.Radiobutton(master,text='MD5',variable=self.hash_radio,value='md5').place(x=271,y=51,width=66)


            self.te2= StringVar()
            ttk.Entry(master,textvariable=self.te2, width = 23).place(x=355,y=218)



    def rest(self):
            self.te2.delete(0,'end')
            self.hash_Radio.setChecked(False)
```

when i try to use the rest button function then it doesn`t work.
i dunno why this happening.
can anyone help me

Comment: please try to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can help. also: what gui interface are you using? tkinter? qt? wxwidgets? ...? please clarify! (ok, looks like tkinter, right?)

Comment: yeah tkinter @hiro protagonist

Answer (score 1):

In ttk for 3.x there is no setChecked method.
Instead you call the widget's state() method:

calling it with no argument returns the stateSpec of the widget for example:

```
widget.state()
returns ('focus', 'selected') # widget has focus and is selected
```

calling it with a stateSpec argument will set the state appropriately, adding a not (!) will reset it

so to reset the above widget:

```
widget.state(["!focus", "!selected"]
```

and calling
`widget.state()` now returns `()`. Note that even if you are only changing one state setting, it still has to be in a list